# Dockerfile. Can a CMD read an Argument?

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docke but I am trying to do something like this in the dockerfile

```
ARG ENV
CMD echo $ENV

CMD [ "manage.py","runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--settings={ENV}" ]
```

And I want to pass the ENV argument from the docker build as build-args.
I want to run django based on the environment(staging/production/etc) but looks like CMD is not reading the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding environment variables is the job of the shell. When you run your manage.py as a JSON type CMD, the python script is run directly and no shell is run.

To have a shell expand the variable, your can do

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=${ENV}"]
```

or, as David suggests

```
CMD manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --settings=${ENV}
```

where Docker will run it in a shell for you, which is arguably nicer.

Comment: Why not use plain-string form; `CMD manage.py runserver ...`?  Docker will provide a shell for you.

Comment: Updated. Thanks. It is nicer that way.